# Docker Images and OS security updates

Tags: docker

Let's consider I'm using the Node.js `10.8.0` `node:10.8.0-jessie` [Docker image](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/10/jessie/Dockerfile) as a base image for my application `Dockerfile`. The application is running stable in production and is not updated for a while (several months).

The Node.js `10.8.0` image is based on the `buildpack-deps:jessie` [image](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/master/jessie/Dockerfile), which itself is based on `buildpack-deps:jessie-scm` [image](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/master/jessie/scm/Dockerfile). This is based on the `buildpack-deps:jessie-curl` [image](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/master/jessie/curl/Dockerfile), whose base [image](https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/blob/4d7d3902589728ef78ae36003e30e3f67efdbc3e/jessie/Dockerfile) is `debian:jessie`.

System / security updates for `Debian Jessie` are released regularly.
In a classic hosted environment I would update my Host using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and I'm fine.

But how do I ensure my running Node.js application in the container gets the latest `Debian Jessie` updates and patches while staying on Node.js `node:10.8.0-jessie`?

Running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` for my application `Dockerfile` in my CI and regularly creating a new Image for my application and re-deploying the container doesn't them the correct way.

As it all starts with the `debian:jessie` image, I would expect this to be updated regularly and all depending images as well.

Then I would rebuild my application image by pulling the Node.js `10.8.0` images again (`--no-cache`) and re-deploy it.

My questions are: is this assumption correct? Is there any official Docker documentation about that workflow which seems essential to me?
How do I get notified about `debian:jessie` and eventually `node:10.8.0-jessie`  image patch releases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preferred workflow is to pull an updated base image, or rebuild your base image if it's locally built. Then rebuild your child images. The only commands you run should be install, not upgrade, if at all possible. For fixing to a specific version of an app, add that version dependency in your install command.

This is preferred over upgrading packages in an existing image for several reasons:

- upgrading images still leaves the old versions of the packages in the image layers, causing your images to grow unnecessarily in size.
- upgrading would require a new Dockerfile for each new release, with the parent image set to the previous version, causing a maintenance challenge.
- reproducing an image created through an upgrade process would require first installing lots of old versions and building up the layers again.
- adding layers for each upgrade reduces performance with the union filesystem. Some of the storage drivers also have limits on how many layers you can create, which would eventually fail after enough iterations of an upgrade cycle.
- upgrades introduce the risk of state drift. If one image in your chain of upgrades included a change that got lost in the chain of Dockerfiles, or the state from a previous install changes how a fresh install runs, you get an unreproducible environment that may break for unknown reasons.

The only scenario where I might perform an upgrade is if an upstream base image is not being maintained. Preferably I'd find a different base image, or build it locally. But when neither of those is possible, I may build a local base image that is a child of the unmaintained external base image, with the first step of upgrading packages. In Dockerfiles, this would look like:

```
FROM scratch as remote-unmaintained
ADD unmaintained.tgz /

FROM remote-unmaintained as local-base
RUN upgrade-cmd

FROM local-base as app
COPY app /
CMD /app
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reliable way to check whether upstream base image get updated regularly?

Comment: You can look at past performance, though that's the past so not reliable for making future predictions. E.g. here's the tag history for the nginx image: https://hub.docker.com/r/library/nginx/tags/. Unfortunately the tag history is less helpful if upstream isn't running builds with different tags.

Comment: But does it mean `nginx:1.15.1` gets updated to `nginx:1.15.2` when just os updates have been done? I would expect that bare metal nginx 1.15.2 to match dockerized `nginx:1.15.2` independent of how often `nginx:1.1.5.2' got os updates.

Comment: You want to update to newer versions of nginx for application patches. In doing so, you'll get patches for the underlying OS if the build includes those. There is no one answer, it all depends on how the repository is built and maintained.

Answer (score -4):

When I want to use Docker images today, I always try to find the `alpine` version of this image. There is reasons behind this:

> Alpine Linux is a security-oriented, lightweight Linux distribution based on musl libc and busybox.
>
> https://alpinelinux.org/

If you don't know already but you're interested in Alpine Linux, I suggest you to navigate through their website.

The good point is that this distribution is well handled by a good community. That signifies the distribution is often updated to integrate new security fixes.

It is important to understand that this is really insteresting (speaking Docker) because, as you said in your question, the built images are immutable through the time.

By using Alpine based images in Docker, you ensure that you have the latest fix from the actual known bugs/security threats. To know how often they update their Docker image, you can check this page: https://hub.docker.com/r/library/alpine/tags/

Every image based on this one will be updated at the same time, and there are many image:

- https://hub.docker.com/_/node/
- https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/
- https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/
- https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/
- https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/
- https://hub.docker.com/_/memcached/
- https://hub.docker.com/_/ (the first in the list)

I don't think my solution is the best but it can help anyway:

On my servers, I created a CRON task that pull every day the Alpine image I'm using, for example [`node:8-alpine`](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/).

After that, whenever I build my applications based on this image, I'm sure I have the latest updates.

If you want to go deeper, you can even build you app after pulling the [`node:8-alpine`](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) image.

For your question about being prevent of new updates/upgrades I don't know how but I you want to use Alpine images you can subscribe to their RSS: https://alpinelinux.org/atom.xml

There are many others reasons to use Alpine images but since it'll be off topic, I'll just give you this article: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/the-3-biggest-wins-when-using-alpine-as-a-base-docker-image

EDIT 1:

Since you have a CI environment and you build your images with, you can regularly create your own Dockerfile where you do your `apt-get update && apt-get install` and then use this image as a base images for your application images. But this way will add layers to your final images and then will increase its size.

Comment: I feel like this doesn't actually answer the OP's question.  Say the base `alpine` image does update; how do you know that the interim `node:8-alpine` image did too, and that you need to apply that to your own image?

Comment: (I also feel like the Alpine images are a little overrated: I see so many Dockerfiles that start by installing a full C toolchain, multiple language runtimes, and developer tools that even if you save 100 MB over a bigger Linux distro it's lost in the noise.)

Comment: My post is mainly answering the "maintain and stable part" of the question. But, for the doubt you gave, you're right: since images are immuable, if you want to update the base image, you need to build it again. Developers add libraries in their Dockerfile because the Alpine image has only the necessary to run commands. But if you need a framework like Node.js you need to install its dependencies, that's normal. The image will still be smaller than the official Node.js image based on Debian or Ubuntu images.